# Можно ли управлять несколькими тригерами одним скриптом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть несколько триггеров и можно-ли с помощью одного скрипта проверять что находится в каждом из них?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что нельзя?

Comment: Просто в взаимодействие с тригером я видел только способ работы с одним. 
То-есть есть триггер на него вешайся скрипт и в этом скрипте прописываются заранее написанные функции по типу(fixedUpdate).
и нет обращения к какому либо триггеру просто, есть тригер и на нём скрип и всё. а других способов я не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно, если логика у этих триггеров небольшая, то можете просто допустим проверять gameobject.name или тег, что бы определить на каком объекте работает скрипт и использовать нужную логику.

А если логика у триггеров большая, не рекомендую так делать.